# Passing value to parent in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass the value from an input button up to its parent.
Here's my child component,

```
class Sidebar extends React.Component {

  handleSubmitButton(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let value = document.getElementById('input-button').value;
    console.log(value);

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

         <input type="text" id="input-button" placeholder="YGUID" />

            <button type="button" className="btn btn-info btn-icons" onClick={this.handleSubmitButton} >

            </button>

      </div>
    );

  }
}

Sidebar.propTypes = {
  handleSubmitButton: React.PropTypes.func
};
```

I want to pass value obtained in handleSubmit button to it parent. This is the parent component.

```
class Parent extends React.Component{

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

  }
handleSubmit(){
.......
  }
render(){
    return(

        <div className="col-md-8 middle-pane">
          <Viewer images={this.state.images} handleSubmitButton = {this.state.handleSubmit} />
        </div>



    );
  }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `handleSubmitButton = {this.state.handleSubmit}` should be `handleSubmitButton = {this.handleSubmit}`. All you have to do is call the handler in the child and pass a value to it, e.g. `this.props.handleSubmitButton(someValue)`.

Comment: @FelixKling I'm new to React, thus a bit lost. Could you write an answer maybe, with a little more explanation.

Comment: Doesn't the duplicate solve your issue? If not, why not?

Comment: I'm equally lost with the duplicate. How do I return the value obtained in the child up to the parent and where do I store it?

Comment: *"How do I return the value obtained in the child up to the parent"* The parent passes a function to the child (`this.handleSubmit`). The child calls that function, thus passing the value to parent: `his.props.handleSubmitButton(someValue)`. What the parent does with the value is up to them. It could "store" the value in its state. There isn't really anything to add besides what is already shown in the other question.